# Canceling shared element transition

Tags: android, android-transitions

I have two activities (A and B), and when I click on a button, element from A start animated transition to B. However, I want to disable that same transition playing backwards when going back from B to A.

Before asking this question, I researched on Internet and found that there are two methods `setSharedElementReturnTransition(transition)` and `setSharedElementReenterTransition(transition)`. Those methods are called in appropriate activities `onCreate()` method with `transition = null` and that didn't work.

Only solution I found, for canceling transition, was calling `finish()` in `onBackPressed()` instead of `super.onBackPressed()`. Is there any other way to achieve desired behavior?

To sum it up, when I set backwards transitions to null nothing changed - transition not overrided.

Edit 1. Here is a code:

**ActivtyA.java**

```
 public class ActivityA {

    ...
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_A);
            }

    ...

            @Override
            public void onPersonalProfileEditIconClicked() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

                      View sharedView = avatarView;

                      String sharedElementName = getString(R.string.profile_avatar);
                      ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation
                                (ActivityA.this, sharedView, sharedElementName);
                      startActivity(intent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
                } else startActivity(intent);
            }
}
```

**ActivityB.java**

```
public class ActivityB {

    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_B);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}
```

In XML files (activity_A and activity_B) sharedView have property transitionName.

**themes.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: I also face the same issue and for me, what i did was `finish()` in `onBackPressed()`

Comment: Did you try
[OverridePendingTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int))

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: @AJay thank you for response. I already did that, but it isn't a solution

Comment: @AtmanBhatt I updated question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After updating support libraries canceling shared element transition is possible, without changing `super.onBackPressed();` to `finish();`

Only you need is to set (in my case) return/reenter transition to null and change transition name on your view.

`getWindow().setSharedElementReturnTransition(null);
 getWindow().setSharedElementReenterTransition(null);
 view.setTransitionName(null);`

Comment: Where do we need to write this code? Inside `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: I think inside `onCreate()` is where I originally put it

Comment: In my case the app crashes when transition animation is started and user presses the back button before the next activity is launched. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can get desired output using below code:
**ActivityA.java**

```
private void startActivityB(){
    startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class));
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_to_right, R.anim.slide_right_to_left);
  }
```

No need to write extra code 
**ActivityB.java**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //TODO
}
```

***OR***

And if you want to finish ActivityA after starting ActivityB then
**ActivityA.java**

```
private void startActivityB(){
      startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityB.class));
      overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_to_right, R.anim.slide_right_to_left);
      finish();
}
```

**ActivityB.java**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class));
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_to_left, R.anim.slide_left_to_right);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: overridePendingTransition is not part of the transition framework, nor has anything to do with shared element transitions, to which the OP's question pertains